# where can i found this class in RegisterUser laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, composer-php, laravel-8

**i installed authentication from laravel.com to the project as laravel 8 but i need to customize the registration route to login route to be both of them in the same page but
like  in this photo in laravel 6** from(auth.register) i need it to (auth.login) to be the register and login form in the same page**

[image]

I've searched a lot among the files even I've written name of the class in search of vs but still no result in the files

[image]

Comment: What **exactly** are you searching for? How is this related to Composer?

Comment: hey @NicoHaase i want to change the default route of register user to another route I do that in laravel 6 by change it from RigersterUser Controller but in laravel 8 I can't found this controller even the register route exists 
I neet to change the route from register to login to be both of them in the same page

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it